# Можно ли сократить условное присваивание

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код

```
x = 3 * y + z
x = x if x > 0 else 0
```

Можно ли это как-то записать в одну инструкцию, но избежать дублирование вычисления `x`? Т.е. не таким образом:

```
x = (3 * y + z) if (3 * y + z) > 0 else 0
```

Comment: А зачем? Не нужно стараться запихнуть как можно больше в одну строку. Код должен оставаться читабельным.

Comment: @Александр Просто то, что было у меня - тоже не есть хорошо. Либо 2 строки кода для, можно сказать, одного выражения, либо одна строка, но с не очевидным кодом, который содержит дублирующиеся вычисления, что само по себе является источником возможных ошибок в будущем.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Я бы написал `max(0, 3 * y + z)`

Comment: элегантно получилось!

Comment: спасибо, действительно лаконично и красиво, как раз этого и хотел.

Comment: еще ужасный способ x = [a if a > 0 else 0 for a in [3 * y + z]][0]