# Открытие приложений в Linux через bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, kali-linux

У меня есть две программы, телеграм и саблайм. Я создал файлы subl и tlg в

> /usr/bin

tlg:

```
#!/bin/bash
 exec /opt/Telegram/Telegram "$@"
```

subl

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```

При открытии саблайма все хорошо: открывается саблайм, и я могу продолжить печатать команды в терминал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В то же время, при открытии телеграмма, консоль не позволяет продолжить вводить команды.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при вводе команды можно было продолжить польоваться терминалом?

Comment: Добавьте & в конец команды.

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но почему же тогда subl работает без амперсанда?

Comment: Просто разные программы стартуют по разному. Саблим видимо внутри себя сам отцепляется от основного процесса. Может у них там свой скрипт или что-то такое. Надо смотреть.

Comment: Всё верно. Телеграм остаётся висеть в трее. Когда вы его закроете, процесс завершится. Саблайм же просто написан по-другому, он запускает дочерний процесс и завершается сразу. Вы можете без опаски во всех случаях использовать & в конце, если вам нужно быть уверенным, что процесс не заблокирует терминал, но имейте ввиду, что следующие вызовы в таком случае (если они есть) будут выполняться не дожидаясь завершения предыдущих.

Comment: @Axenow почему вы написали ответ в комментариях? Не надо так! Ответы принято писать ниже :)

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Это даже не ответ - 3 слова, 1 предлог и 1 символ. ) Я в ответы стараюсь писать что-то, что хотя бы большое. )

Comment: У саблайма есть опция `-w`, с которой он точно так же будет ждать закрытия, как и телеграм

Comment: @Axenow [вы недооцениваете мощь ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/561712) :D

Comment: @andreymal Я понял, спасибо - буду знать )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае, если вам надо открыть приложение в фоне, чтобы командная строка потом освободилась, просто добавьте в конец символ: `&`.